# build_pdf is "blocked" by other process

Tags: python, latex

Well this is my python code:

```
min_latex = (r"\documentclass{article}"
             r"\begin{document}"
             r"Hello, world!"
             r"\end{document}")

from latex import build_pdf

pdf = build_pdf(min_latex)
```

I get the following error when I try to compile&run it. I have no idea what process is using this file. I had also rebooted pc, checked taskmanager for any pdf/latex releated processes and no luck I guess.

```
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'c:\\users\\****\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tmpokrrfs\\tmp2acqs_.latex'
Exception WindowsError: WindowsError(32, 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process') in <bound method TempDir.__del__ of <tempdir.TempDir object at 0x02282B90>> ignored
```